# Is a connection of 1 hour at CDG airport realistic?

Tags: short-connections, cdg

This January I will have a connection on a single ticket by KLM/Air France - presumably from terminal 2D to terminal 2E, on a Schengen to International flight. Is this a realistic time or is there a large chance I won't make the connection?

Of course, I'd be glad to get a free hotel and a 600 EUR bonus for the missed connection, but it would be nice to know in advance if there's a large chance of this happening.

Comment: 2D to 2E, domestic(ish) to international, doesn't require to pass through security again (been there done that). So one hour is definitely doable, but that requires you hustle, and know where you're going. Last time I did it in 30.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 hour is right on the minimum connection time for most such connections at CDG (it actually depends on the exact flights, but the general Domestic-to-International time is 1 hour).

Exactly how feasible this is will depend on how busy the airport is at the time (including immigration and security), how you decide to get between terminals, and whether your flights are on time.

To give you an example, two days ago I connected international to international at CDG.  We arrived at a bus gate into Terminal 2C.  From the time the door opened to when I arrived at the new gate was 46 minutes - and that was with me sitting at the front of the plane, having priority access for security, no immigration, and moving through the airport as quickly as possible without actually running!

Presuming you are booked on a single ticket, if you miss your connection the airline will be responsible for re-routing you, however you will NOT automatically be due compensation as you've implied - if will depend on a number of factors.

For example, if the inbound flight was on time and you simply didn't make it to the gate in time (even if making it wasn't possible due to queues at security/immigration, the use of a bus gate, or simply the time it took you to get there) then NO compensation will be due.  Even if your inbound flight was delayed, it will depend on the reason it was delayed.

So yes, 1 hour is realistic - if **everything** goes right.  If you need to get to your destination on time, I would strongly suggest NOT taking this connection.  If you're willing to roll the dice and risk having to catch a later flight, then go for it...

Comment: Last year I had a 45 minutes connection in CDG, from Italy to UK. So Schengen to extra-Schengen. 
The first flight was slightly late. 
No security controls and the personnel let me skip the line for passport controls, but I had to run between terminals and eventually I missed the flight. I have been moved to a later flight for free. In my opinion 1 hour is very tight.

Answer (score 3):

Did this today, which probably means my answer is a bit skewed as it was a Sunday, so less busy than normal. From doors opening on the inbound flight in terminal 2D it took only **20 minutes** to reach the M gates in terminal 2E. So I'd say the answer is yes, it's quite realistic even if your flight is half an hour late.